# Fetch attributes from to many relationship in Swift Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data

I cannot for the life of me get this to work. I have a 'Match' entity and a 'Players' entity joined by a many-to-many relationship. For each match I am trying to create a string of names that are pulled from the Players entity in Core Data. Here is the latest incarnation of what I have been trying to achieve this with:

```
let players = matchData[indexPath.row].value(forKeyPath: "players") as? NSManagedObject
    let playerNames = players?.value(forKey: "firstName") as? NSMutableArray

    let playersString = playerNames?.componentsJoined(by: ",")
```

`matchData` is the `NSManagedObject` where my fetched data is held. "players" is the name of the relationship to the "Players" entity. And "firstName" is the attribute that I am trying to string together.

This however returns 'nil' for each match even though I know for sure that there are player records saved for each match. I can display other matchData items fine but am having trouble with this to-many relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value(forKeyPath: "players") as? NSManagedObject`

If `players` is really a to-many relationship then this code will always return nil, because it will try to cast to an `NSManagedObject` but the actual type is a `Set` of `NSManagedObject`s.

`value(forKeyPath: "players") as? Set<NSManagedObject>` will get you past the first hurdle.

You'd be doing yourself a favour to specify managed object subclasses as well, then you'll have properties generated for all of these things which will make your code much cleaner and easier to understand.

Comment: thanks. I'll see how i get on with that. And yes - totally agree about moving to a subclass approach!